# Advanced SQL join

Tags: sql

I have to tables `WO` and `PO`. Both tables can be linked by the `WO#` field.

#### WO table

WO fields

```
WO#
WO_Date
```

#### PO table

PO fields

```
PO#
PO_Date
WO#
```

In the PO table there are several `PO#` linked to the same `WO#`.
I need a query that returns the following fields BUT the caveat is that I should only return one record per `WO#` and join the only the `PO#` with the highest date from the matching records in the PO table
`WO# WO_Date PO# PO_Date` (the highest date of all those `PO#` matching the same `WO#`)

I’m using MS Query to read data out of an Oracle DB.

Comment: and what attempts have you made yourself thus far?

Comment: @Gonzalez - Please can you reformat your question. It's a bit difficult to read as one solid block of text. Perhaps splitting up the tables, and putting each column on a seperate line? Thanks.

Comment: Are the PO#'s sequential? If we can assume the highest PO# matches the highest PO_Date, the query is a _lot_ simpler.

Comment: Also, are the PO_date's unique, as least within a specific WO? If the dates are unique, we can just build a correlated subquery to match a specific PO record on date alone. If you might have duplicate PO_Dates per WO, we need to also create a projection to ensure unique rows.

Comment: thanks, they are not sequentianl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PO#'s are sequential, such that the highest PO# matches the highest date:

```
SELECT wo.WO#. WO_Date, MAX(PO#) "PO#", MAX(PO_Date) "PO_Date"
FROM [WO]
LEFT JOIN [PO] on wo.WO# = po.WO#
GROUP BY wo.WO#, WO_Date
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM WO
JOIN (SELECT 
          *,
          ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY WO# ORDER BY WO_Date DESC) AS RowNo
      FROM PO
    ) PO
ON PO.WO# = WO.WO#
WHERE PO.RowNo = 1
```

I'd also suggest an `INDEX` on `WO_Date` if you are likely to have lots of records.

You may want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead if you are likely to have `WO's` that have no corresponding `PO` records, and adjust the `WHERE CLAUSE` to be `WHERE PO.RowNo = 1 OR PO.WO# IS NULL`.

Comment: That is actually ANSI standard SQL, not specific to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, that I didn't know!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to join using a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM WO
JOIN (SELECT PO#, MAX(PO_Date) PO_DATE
      FROM PO
      GROUP BY PO#
     )PO
ON WO.WO# = PO.PO#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From WO w
  left Join PO p
      On p.WO# = w.WO#
         And p.PO_Date =
           (Select Max(PO_Date)
            From PO
            Where WO# = w.WO#)
```

Comment: Will probably work, but if there can be more than 1 PO on the same date for a given WO it could produce duplicate records.